# How can I ignore variable lengths differ error in R ? (I need to regress 1 on other variables)

Tags: r, regression

Hi I am trying to get Heteroskedasticity-Robust LM Statistic via this.
This is wooldridge textbook data and example but in the end I get this error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = 1 ~ ML + ML2 - 1, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'ML')
```

The code is,

```
library(wooldridge)
attach(crime1)

avgsensq = (avgsen^2)

#UNRESTRICTED MODEL

MODEL3 = lm(narr86 ~ pcnv + avgsen + avgsensq + ptime86 + qemp86 + inc86 +
              black+hispan)

summary(MODEL3)

MODEL3_1 = lm(narr86 ~ pcnv + ptime86 + qemp86 + inc86 +
              black+hispan)

RES1 = residuals(MODEL3_1)

MODEL3_2 = lm(avgsen ~pcnv + ptime86+qemp86+inc86+black+hispan)
MODEL3_3= lm(avgsensq ~pcnv + ptime86+qemp86+inc86+black+hispan)

RES2 = residuals(MODEL3_2)
RES3 = residuals(MODEL3_3)

ML = RES1*RES2
ML2 = RES1*RES3

MODEL3_4 = lm(1 ~ ML + ML2 - 1)
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `lm` function doesn't seem to work with a single value as the response variable. If you really want to have a constant response, you need to specify it as a vector that has the same length as the terms, so doing:

```
MODEL3_4 = lm(rep(1, length(ML)) ~ ML + ML2 - 1)
MODEL3_4 
#
#Call:
#lm(formula = rep(1, length(ML)) ~ ML + ML2 - 1)
# 
#Coefficients:
#       ML        ML2  
# 0.027785  -0.001045
```